# Keras: changing strides doesn't seem to be changing the number of parameters in conv2d/conv3d

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I may be missing something simple here, but when I change the number of strides in convolution layers, I'm not getting a corresponding change in the number of parameters to be fit. Consider these:

```
from keras import layers as L
x=L.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1),padding='valid')(input)
y=L.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2),padding='valid')(input)
z=L.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(3,3),padding='valid')(input)
```

I thought that strides of (3,3) would have 3-times fewer filters being laid down in each dimension and therefore a correspondingly-smaller number of parameters to be fit. And yet, this isn't the case.

If my input layer has size (none,63,143,32) -- I'm feeding it a squeezed down output of a conv3d -- then the number of parameters of the convolutions is always 9248, regardless of stride. Sooo...what am I missing?

Comment: Number of parameters in CNN is free of input and pading and strides. They only affect the shape of the output. Here you have 3 X 3 kernels with depth = 32. You also have 32 feature maps for each layer. So total number of parameters for one layer is (3 X 3 X 32) X 32 + 32 = 9248 (the addition is for biases. You have 32 kernels, so 32 different biases.

Answer (score 2):

Convolution filters never depend on the size of the image, the padding, the strides, etc.

They depend only on `kernel_size` and `filters`.

Their shape is: `(kernel_size[0], kernel_size[1], input_filters, output_filters)`

I suggest you read [this page](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/conv_arithmetic.html) that explains a lot about convolutions with sliding images, although they don't represent the input channels in the images.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. And I feel pretty addle that I missed that subtlety. Thanks!